# Detect beacon (iNode) in background

Tags: swift, iphone, beacon, inode

I'm trying to build an application for registering in/out time. I want to detect when the person enters the location and send a request with the access timestamp to my server. Everything in background - without taking the phone out of the pocket. Right now I'm using CoreBluetooth and CoreLocation, but it only works in foreground, when user clicks a button. How can I do it in background? Is it posible on iPhone?

Comment: without codes and `Info.plist`, it is impossible to diagnose your issue.

Comment: In info.plist I've set all needed keys.  When user click on button I got iNode. But.. can I do it in background on IPhone?